# Hive not showing the table data even after doing MSCK REPAIR TABLE

Tags: hive

I was having a scenario: Hive data type change for an external hive partitioned table say n1. I am not getting the data after following below steps.

---

I followed below steps:

```
>>created new table n2 with new datatype
>>dynamically inserted data in n2 from original table n1
>>Then follows below steps to rename the table to original name :n1
>>ALTER TABLE n1 DROP IF EXISTS PARTITION (partition_date>'0');
>>hadoop fs -rm -r hdfs://FajitaDevelopment/data/gfctwnsg/staging/hive/gfctwnsg_staging/n1/partition_date*/*
>>MSCK repair table n1;
>>DROP TABLE n1;
>>ALTER TABLE n2 RENAME TO n1;
>>hadoop fs -rm -r hdfs://FajitaDevelopment/data/gfctwnsg/staging/hive/gfctwnsg_staging/n1/*
>>hadoop fs –mv hdfs://FajitaDevelopment/data/gfctwnsg/staging/hive/gfctwnsg_staging/n2/*  hdfs://FajitaDevelopment/data/gfctwnsg/staging/hive/gfctwnsg_staging/n1
>>MSCK repair table n1;
>>Alter table n1 SET LOCATION   'hdfs://FajitaDevelopment/data/gfctwnsg/staging/hive/gfctwnsg_staging/n1' ;
        MSCK repair table n1;
```

****Please let me know ,why i am not getting data after rename table.

## Table is pointing to:****  hdfs://FajitaDevelopment/data/gfctwnsg/staging/hive/gfctwnsg_staging/n1

```
    >> `MSCK REPAIR TABLE n1;`
    >> `hadoop fs -ls -R hdfs://FajitaDevelopment/data/gfctwnsg/staging/hive/gfctwnsg_staging/n1`
    drwxrwx--x+  - hive hive          0 2018-08-31 02:42 hdfs://FajitaDevelopment/data/gfctwnsg/staging/hive/gfctwnsg_staging/n1/partition_date=2017-11-28
    -rwxrwx--x+  3 hive hive       8205 2018-08-31 02:42 hdfs://FajitaDevelopment/data/gfctwnsg/staging/hive/gfctwnsg_staging/n1/partition_date=2017-11-28/000000_0
    drwxrwx--x+  - hive hive          0 2018-08-31 02:42 hdfs://FajitaDevelopment/data/gfctwnsg/staging/hive/gfctwnsg_staging/n1/partition_date=2018-01-15
                -rwxrwx--x+  3 hive hive       7032 2018-08-31 02:42 hdfs://FajitaDevelopment/data/gfctwnsg/staging/hive/gfctwnsg_staging/n1/partition_date=2018-01-15/000003_0
                drwxrwx--x+  - hive hive          0 2018-08-31 02:42 hdfs://FajitaDevelopment/data/gfctwnsg/staging/hive/gfctwnsg_staging/n1/partition_date=2018-08-09
                -rwxrwx--x+  3 hive hive       7143 2018-08-31 02:42 hdfs://FajitaDevelopment/data/gfctwnsg/staging/hive/gfctwnsg_staging/n1/partition_date=2018-08-09/000002_0
    drwxrwx--x+  - hive hive          0 2018-08-31 02:42 hdfs://FajitaDevelopment/data/gfctwnsg/staging/hive/gfctwnsg_staging/n1/partition_date=2018-08-16
    -rwxrwx--x+  3 hive hive       7501 2018-08-31 02:42 hdfs://FajitaDevelopment/data/gfctwnsg/staging/hive/gfctwnsg_staging/n1/partition_date=2018-08-16/000001_0
    =================================================
    >>show partitions n1;

                +----------------------------+--+
                |         partition          |
                +----------------------------+--+
                | partition_date=2017-11-28  |
                | partition_date=2018-01-15  |
                | partition_date=2018-08-09  |
                | partition_date=2018-08-16  |
                +----------------------------+--+
                ==============================================

>> select count(*),partition_date from n1 group by partition_date;


                +------+-----------------+--+
                | _c0  | partition_date  |
                +------+-----------------+--+
                +------+-----------------+--+
                =========================================
                ****Here is the issue, it is not showing the data.****
```

Comment: Please have a look at the formatting of your question. There is a nice "edit help" section, explaining how you properly format your content. I started to improve formatting, but well: it is simply not clear in your question how things should be grouped together. So I can only suggest you to improve your question yourself. You should understand that indenting with 4 tabs creates the "grey" sections (used for *code*), and that using ">" creates yellow "quote" sections.

Comment: try to add some partition manualy with `alter table n1 add partition (...) location ...`.

Comment: it will not solve my issue, i want to check , what happens to my existing partitions.

Comment: I tried alter table n1 add partition (...) location .... –, it says ,partition already exists and that is true.